# Accessing git commands from the file manager

Tags: 16.04, files, git

Is there a way to do git commands from the Files manager in Ubuntu 16.04? E.g: commit changes, push, pull, etc.

Comment: Did you mean from a Graphical User Interface?

Comment: @daumie I mean that, when I see a file in the standard file-manager, I can right-click the file, then select e.g. "commit" and the file will be committed.

Comment: @Pabi  that question was from 2010.  The top answer says to use RabbitVCS, but RabbitVCS is not working well with 14.04 and 16.04.

Comment: @Pabi additionally, when I go to Help->About in my default 16.04 file manager, it does not say "Nautilus", it only says "Files".

Comment: Yes it is named files in the menue, it is nonetheless nautilus. The newest version (v0.16.0) should work fine with 16.04.

Comment: See here: https://github.com/rabbitvcs/rabbitvcs/issues/162 an open issue claiming an error and in stability on 16.04.  Also, here: http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu/dists/ there is no version for xenial.

Comment: @DavidFoerster did he ask for GUI clients for Git? I don't think he did.

Comment: @AnwarShah: Ok, then it's at least very closely related to the question.